# How do I stop my script from running on refresh and just on the OnClick?

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML

```
<h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
<span id="number">0</span>
<button id="generateBtn">Generate</button>
<script src="js/randomnumber.js"></script>
```

This is my Javascript

```
const number = document.getElementById('number');
const generateBtn = document.getElementById('generateBtn');

const randomGenerator = () => {
  const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10 + 1);
   number.textContent = randomnumber;
};

generateBtn.addEventListener('click',randomGenerator);
randomGenerator();
```

So, every time I refresh the page it runs the javascript again. Any tips on how I prevent this from happening again ?  All the code works I just need it to work only Onclick

Comment: Remove `randomGenerator();` - You're calling the function once after adding the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

in the end of the code there's `randomGenerator();`

so its run when you refresh the page, not on click so remove it
and keep it like this bellow:

```js
generateBtn.addEventListener('click',randomGenerator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Remove this randomGenerator(); from last line.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const number = document.getElementById('number');
const generateBtn = document.getElementById('generateBtn');

const randomGenerator = () => {
  const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10 + 1);
   number.textContent = randomnumber;
};

generateBtn.addEventListener('click',randomGenerator);
```

```html
<h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
<span id="number">0</span>
<button id="generateBtn">Generate</button>
<script src="js/randomnumber.js"></script>
```

Remove `randomGenerator();` - You're calling the function once after adding the event listener. I've provided an example above.